# Subclassing UITextField and setting text font

Tags: ios, uitextfield, subclassing

I have a subclass of UITextField so that I can add an IndexPath item to the textfield that looks like this:

```
@interface jnTextField : UITextField

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSIndexPath *indexPath;

@end
```

Then I added the textfield to a UITableViewCell in InterfaceBuilder. However now when I try to set text color and font it doesn't set like if I was using the standard UITextField. What else do I need to override to get this working. I wasn't able to find anything explaining what I am missing. The code I am using to change text font/color/text is my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method:

```
cell.textField.text = @"add url";
cell.textField.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Light" size:14.0];
cell.textField.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
```

Comment: I hope the term `placeholder` that you are using is wrong here. Will you please correct it. Is that your question about setting `text` or `placeholder` property?

Comment: Off topic remark: Don't start you class name with lower case.

Comment: Please show the complete `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.

Comment: No worries... we all are here just to learn something... let me post the solution for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here... you have to avoid using the same property names used by `UIKIT` classes.

```
cell.textField.text = @"add url";
cell.textField.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Light" size:14.0];
cell.textField.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
```

The `textField` is a property of `UITableViewCell` class therefore please change the `custom UITextField's` (jnTextField) name in your `custom UITabelViewCell` class something like.

```
cell.myCustomTextField.text = @"add url";
cell.myCustomTextField.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Light" size:14.0];
cell.myCustomTextField.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
```

To achieve that you might have to case the cell like this

```
MYCustomCell *myCell = (MYCustomCell *)cell

myCell.myCustomTextField.text = @"add url";
myCell.myCustomTextField.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Light" size:14.0];
myCell.myCustomTextField.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Thanks for your help, didn't even think of it!